# Using \n at the end of html code in servlets

Tags: java, html, servlets

So, I'm currently reading Coreservlets by Marty Hall. This is his example of a servlet- generating html.

```
    response.setContentType("text/html");
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
    out.println
      ("<!DOCTYPE html>\n" +
       "<html>\n" +
       "<head><title>A Test Servlet</title></head>\n" +
       "<body bgcolor=\"#fdf5e6\">\n" +
       "<h1>Test</h1>\n" +
       "<p>Simple servlet for testing.</p>\n" +
       "</body></html>");
```

I don't know what's the newline doing here, because when I change it to:

```
    response.setContentType("text/html");
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
    out.println
      ("<!DOCTYPE html>" +
       "<html>" +
       "<head><title>A Test Servlet</title></head>" +
       "<body bgcolor=\"#fdf5e6\">" +
       "<h1>Test</h1>" +
       "<p>Simple servlet for testing.</p>" +
       "</body></html>");
```

It still works.

So, what's the newline doing in this code? Am I missing something?

Comment: To make the output *human* readable.

Comment: It doesn't do much. HTML collapses whitespace outside of preformatted tags. All it does is make the outputted source more readable when viewed.